# I'm looking for information on ancient civilisations in D&D 5e

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, lore, world-building

My party are engaged in the exploration of ancient ruins and underways in support of a party of elven archeologists.  My character is a mountain dwarf with a special proficiency in identifying the origins of stonework and the history of stone structures.  So, I'm looking for reference sources that explain the ancient Civilisations of the D&D 5e universe and some background on their evolutions and eventual fate.

Comment: Can you narrow down the question by providing which setting you are playing in? Each setting has its own deep rich background.

Comment: Hi Didz, and welcome to the site! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep, you'll be able to join us in [chat]. As Ian Miller points out there's some different settings available — are you playing in the default, which is Forgotten Realms?

Comment: Just curious.. "eleven archaeologists" or "elven archaeologists"?

Comment: Hi Ian,  the DM has not specifically specified which setting he is drawing his inspiration from.  But given that the default setting for D&D 5e is Forgotten Realms and the calendar we have been given has been taken from that source book I think its safe to assume that Forgotten Realms is the setting.

Comment: Hi Erik, I've corrected the typo so it now reads 'elven archaeologists'.

We met two of them last night and apparently they are searching for evidence of early elven civilisations amongst the ruins of the area we are questing in.

Comment: Even knowing what setting you're asking about, this is far too broad. An answer here is far too short to contain anything meaningful about every ancient civilisations in the Forgotten Realms' past. There are multiple real books on the subject. What do you need to know? What will you use it for?

Comment: Well as I said above we are escorting a group of elven archeologists, who are exploring ancient ruins in a remote area, and my character is a Mountain dwarf with particular proficiency in the history and construction of stonework.  So, I'm looking to discover as much as I can about Ancient D&D civilizations , so that when (and if) I spot something I can convey some pertinent and accurate information to both the elves and my fellow party members.

Comment: For example: So, far we have explored four levels of a catacomb, which is of human construction and of old but rather poor construction.   However, on the fourth level there is a chamber where the floor has collapsed into a much old elven underway and I'm hoping initially to find out more about ancient elven civilisations to perhaps determine its likely purpose or history.

Comment: Fwiw, **this should be reopened**. The question was always silly (these particular ruins say whatever the campaign GM says they do) but it was perfectly straightforward and was asking for major sources concerning the ancient civilizations of the Forgotten Realms recent enough that their ruins would be discoverable. It's a useful thing to have people mention, and it's silly to pretend that there are far too many to possibly list. At worst, it just requires a community wiki answer.